# Implementing Sort URLs Regex Using Unix Commands

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, sort, gawk, url

I am a newbie to regular expressions as they manifest in things such as sed, awk, sort, grep and other Unix binaries.

I know that if I sort a list of URLs in my text editor (BBEdit) using this regular expression:

```
(https?)://([a-z0-9]+[.])*(.+?)[.](.+?)/(.*)$
\3\t\4\t\2\t\5\t\1
```

It produces the end result I desire.

I'd like to sort this on the Unix command line so it can be done automatically without me triggering the sort in BBEdit's GUI.  However, I don't have enough knowledge of sed, awk, sort, etc. to be able to translate this appropriately.

If anyone could assist me with an answer and perhaps also a little education, it'd be deeply appreciated.  (I do have the GNU versions of these commands available to me, and if it matters, my current shell is zsh.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
cat urls.txt | sed -r -e "s|(https?)://([a-z0-9]+[.])*(.+?)[.](.+?)/(.*)$|\3\t\4\t\2\t\5\t\1|g"
```

I'm not a `sed` export, but the contruction `sed -e -r "s|someregex|replacedwitthis|g" < somefile.txt` can come in pretty handy. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!  I did ```pbpaste | gsed -r -e "s/(https?):\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*(.+?)[.](.+?)\/(.*)$/\3\t\4\t\2\t\5\t\1/g" | sort | gsed -r -e "s/(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)/\5:\/\/\3\1\.\2\/\4/g" | pbcopy``` to fully implement the sort as I desired.

Comment: The `/` of `s/` in the sed command is actually the field separator. So instead of escaping all those forward slashes you can do: `s|(https?)://` (and the rest of the command) which reads a bit nicer. It turns the `s/pattern/replace/` structure into `s|pattern|replace|` - I like to use pipes, but I think you can use pretty much any symbol.

Comment: @forquare I always forget this great option. I edited my answer.